# wpf datagrids binding and SelectionMode Single

Tags: wpf, binding, grid

I had two datagrids in wpf: grid1 for all available plans and grid2 for the plans been selected.  The two grids are separated by two buttons (>) and (<).  Button (>) is to add the selected plan to the grid2 of associated plans and remove it from grid1. Button (<) is to remove selected item of grid2 and add it to grid1 (to remove from selected plans).

```
<DataGrid  Name="grdAllPlans" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
<Button Click="linkClicked">
<Button Click="UnlinkClicked">
<DataGrid  Name="grdSelectedPlans" SelectionMode="Single" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
```

I had two global variables that have the plans:

```
static List<PlanDTO> PlansAssociated = new List<PlanDTO>();  //contain plans selected
static List<PlanDTO> PlansAvailable = new List<PlanDTO>();   //contain all plans not selected
```

This is the method call to associate a plan (remove from grid1 and add it to grid2):

```
private void linkClicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

            if (grdAllPlans.SelectedItem != null)
            {
                PlanDTO selectedPlan = (PlanDTO)grdAllPlans.SelectedItem;
                PlansAvailable.Remove(selectedPlan); //remove from collection PlansAvailable
                PlansAssociated.Add(selectedPlan); //add it to selected collection

                //Update grid1 
                srcCollectionViewAvailable.Source = PlansAvailable;
                grdPlansDisponibles.ItemsSource = srcCollectionViewAvailable.View;

        //Update grid2
        srcCollectionViewAssociated.Source = PlansAssociated;
        grdPlansAsociés.ItemsSource = srcCollectionViewAssociated.View;

                grdPlansAsociés.UnselectAll();
                grdPlansDisponibles.UnselectAll();
            }

    }
```

The problem it is not working.  The first time that I add a plan to the selected plan grid it do it well, but after that both grid do not get refresh. 
Also SelectionMode="Single" do not work.  I am been able to select multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use ObservableCollection, instead of List for those 2 global variables.

The problem is that the UI wasn't notified when list changes.  Using ObservableCollection would notify the UI automatically.